# "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space” error in Apache Spark?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, out-of-memory

I have a dataframe and I want to convert a column to a Set in spark scala. But It  happen an error `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` when converting. My data so large, about 50,000,000 records 100GB in mongodb. I had read it to a datafame.

```
val readConf1 = ReadConfig(Map("uri" -> "mongodb://127.0.0.1/product-repository.detail?readPreference=primaryPreferred"))
val dff = MongoSpark.load(sc, readConf1).toDF()
val setUrl=dff.select(collect_list("DetailUrl")).first().getList[String](0).toSet
```

This is my spark conf:

```
spark.executor.memory 4G
spark.executor.instances 12
spark.executor.cores 4
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions -Xms3600m
```

It runs normally with small data, below 1,000,000 records. How to solve this error??

Comment: the problem is that collect all 50,000,000 records on a single node, by doing this you destroy scalability; apparently this is too much data for your available memory. Have you tried `collect_set` instead? What is your ultimate goal, what do you ant to do with `setUrl`?

Comment: It seems you are just selecting first row, wondering why it would throw OutOfMemory. Is your List too big ??

Comment: @RaphaelRoth setUrl is a dictionary, I will use it to check value of another dataframe. I don't know collect_set, I'm newbie in spark :(

Comment: @Amit I want to convert a column of df to a set, That is the reference code :( I want a dictionary so the List so big

Comment: @HiệpBạch If you goal is to interact with another dataframe, then use `join`

Comment: I had tried using `join` but not success, data after join too too big although i had `filter`